# What Salesforce license to use for Force.com sites, but no CRM access

Tags: force.com-sites, licenses

Here's a high level overlook- we have multiple Force.com sites which collect multi-page form submission, but we'd like to be able to authenticate that site user.  Currently, we mitigate this with simple email validation or similar, but ideally we'd leverage a Salesforce license to maintain that authentication.

Is there a license that would allow us to validate a user's identity prior to accessing a Force.com site, but restrict them from having any access to our CRM (Salesforce proper).  Once authenticated, that user would complete form submissions on those Force.com sites, which generate standard/custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore employee community licence or community licence for your requirement .

With customer community licence you should be able to provide authenticated experience and enforce security